# Install Old Computer's Hard Drive On A New Computer?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-8.1, upgrade, disk-encryption

After my laptop got messed up I switched to my HTPC (Intel i3, HD Graphics 2000, 500GB refurbed WD HDD, Windows 7, and a P8H77-I mini ITX Asus Motherboard). I have the hard drive from my previous laptop (HP G7, 500gb, Toshiba, with Windows 8.1), and would like to install it on my new computer. The old drive is encrypted with TC, and has all of my old files on it. The HTPC's installation doesn't matter to me.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question.  Are there specific issues you are concerned about?  The Windows license? Encryption? Compatibility?  Are you talking about swapping hard drives?

Comment: @fixer1234 I just want to swap drives, and keep all of the data and programs on the Windows 8.1 drive. I was just trying to be as thorough as possible mentioning the encryption and LOss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hardware is different, for the sake of performance, your best bet would be to do a new OS installation on the HTPC and just move your old files there.

Technically, you can move the hdd to the HTPC and install its hardware drivers and pray that Windows detects, recognizes and accepts all the new hardware at the same time, however the potential for conflicts is huge.

Comment: Everything went off without a hitch actually :) I just popped it in, uninstalled my old graphics drivers and installed New ones, and everything worked like before.